# Heavy right skewed target

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, data-science-model, preprocessing, data-analysis

I scrapped Data science job postings of almost 1000 jobs for salary prediction. I wanted to bin the salary column and build a classification model from the job descriptions. But the (salary)target is heavily skewed right. What should I do here? Should I do log transform and build a regression model? What is the right way to bin the target?[image: Image is the histogram of the salary column]

Comment: Logging the variable can make sense to put the analysis in terms of a percentage change (doubling of halving of salary might be more meaningful than getting an extra 50k). However, you don’t necessarily have to do anything but work with the raw data. What do you want to learn from your data? What would classification have solved for you? What would a regression solve for you, with or without a logarithm?

Comment: Well I found out that most of the job postings had missing salary prospects. The salary information of some was already provided in a range but was in terms of hourly, monthly, annually. I just converted all of them to a an annual estimate  and then tried to bin them. But the heavy skew made me wonder if I should perform classification or regression. I  originally wanted to find under what range of salary the rest of the missing jobs fell under.

Comment: In my view, it's far more natural to use regression instead of classification here, because of quasi-continuous type of data. Creating classes could be unnatural here and afterwards, most classification approaches will try to do regression internally to return the class as an output.
However, an interesting goal could be a prediction of the best/worst-paid data scientist and here classification might be more natural and bring a better interpretation of the model.